# Android emulator reports unknown virtual device

Tags: eclipse, android

i am having the same problem described in the following post "Android emulator reports unknown virtual device" [Why does the Android emulator report "unknown virtual device", when the device is in my user directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384070/android-emulator-reports-unknown-virtual-device) and have followed all of the instructions in an attempt to resolve but still i cannot run my AVD.

I only have one drive on my Windows 7 machine (C:) and the AVD is being created in the correct location -> `C:\Users\MyUser\.android`

Ive also tried to setup an environment variable "ANDROID_SDK_HOME"

The actual error is:

```
emulator: ERROR: unknown virtual device name: 'my_AVD' 
emulator: could not find virtual device named 'my_AVD'
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For another reason i had to re-format my pc. After a quick rebuild its working fine now. I think the problem happened because in the previous installation of windows, i was playing around with HDD's. Somehow this had caused problems..

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below steps to solve the above issue -

1. in task manager kill adb in process
2. in android sdk folder .. /tools/ run adb kill-server in command line
3. Check the avd folder name in " ../.adroid/avd/" - say it is "avd1"
4. run command "emulator -avd avd1 " under android folder "../tool/" in command line

it will start the avd1 device

Now start the eclipse and run your project with setting the "manula" option in configuration.

It will ask for choosing the avd between "avd1" and the existing list of avd's in eclipse if any. You choose "avd1" as it is already running.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: you should have a copy od .android in `C:\<your user name>\`.